# Spreading props on a component and destructuring inside a components with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm wondering what the best way is to use props spreading and destructing in combination with components.

I'm spreading my props like this:

`<RepositoryItem {...node} />`

And after I'm destructuring my props in the component like this:

```js
interface RepositoriesProps {
  name: string
  url: string
}

const RepositoryItem: React.FC<RepositoriesProps> = ({ name, url }) => {
  return (
    <div className="repository_item">
      {name} {url}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Of course, doing it like this I get the following error: `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RepositoriesProps': name, url` on the first part where I'm calling the component.

How can I fix this? Or is it better to just don't use props spreading?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should directly specify type

```
const RepositoryItem: React.FC<RepositoriesProps> = ({ name, url }: RepositoriesProps) => {
```

and your `node` should has type extending `RepositoriesProps`
node: `MyNode` 
where `MyNode` is `interface MyNode extends RepositoriesProps {}`
But basically i think you should just define interface for `node` contains `url` and `name` to give typecript some knowledge (not `{}`)

Comment: THank you for your answer! But what do you mean with: and your node should has type extending RepositoriesProps?